# When all shares of a secret are given to adversary as a permuted matrix

Tags: cryptanalysis, secret-sharing, permutation

Suppose we have a secret $\sigma$.

The secret comes from a universe in which the elements are not necessarily distributed uniformly.

We split $\sigma$ into $n$ shares $[\sigma_1,...,\sigma_n]$ (using Shamir secret sharing). So the order of shares matters.

We know given all the shares in the right order one can recover the secret.

We permute all the shares in a matrix (see below). We fill the empty indices with some dummy (or random) values $d_{i,j}$ 
\begin{matrix}
    d_{11}       & \sigma_{n} & \sigma_{2} & \dots & d_{1,m} \\
    d_{21}       & d_{22} & \sigma_{i} & \dots & d_{2,m} \\
    \dots                                   \\
    d_{k,1}       & d_{k,2} & \sigma_{3} & \dots & \sigma_{1}
\end{matrix}

---

**Question:** Given the matrix, can the adversary recover the secret with a high (or non-negligible) probability?

I emphasis that $\sigma$ may have very greater distribution probability than the other elements of the universe and the adversary knows that probability.

Please note that the values $k$ (number of rows) and $m$ (number of columns) are independent of the number of shares $n$ and we can increase them if it's needed.

====================================

Edit: 
Newly added:

Suppose we have two permuted matrices one contains shares of secret value $\sigma$ and dummy values; and the other matrix contains shares of $\gamma$ and random values. We give away the two permuted matrices and one-to-one mapping of the elements to the adversary. The mapping tells the adversary that value in $i,j$ position in one matrix corresponds to value $k,l$ position in the other matrix.

**Question**: Would the adversary learn the secret values $\sigma$ and $\gamma$ with a non-negligible probability.

Comment: Are you doing $n$-out-of-$n$ secret sharing or $t$-out-of-$n$ with $t<n$?

Comment: @mikeazo As I want to give away all the shares, I'd say $n$-out-of-$n$ secret sharing.

Comment: Is the permutation fixed or how is the permutation generated?

Comment: @mikeazo  We assign a random index (in the matrix) to each share. In nutshell we are using a pseudorandom function whose key is secret and unknown to the adversary to generate a random index. The rest of indices are occupied with some dummy values.

Comment: Does the adversary know the distribution of $\sigma$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Yes, it does.

Comment: I do not have a proof, but assuming you randomly permute the matrix and as the shares will be indistinguishable from random it appears to me that the only way for the adversary to reconstruct the message will be to try all configurations of n messages from the matrix. If the distribution of $\sigma$ is distinguishable from random the adversary may then be able to check if it got the right message with high probability. If this is true N does probably not have to be very much larger than n to hide the message.

Comment: Actually, assuming $n$ is proportional to your security parameter, simply randomly permuting the shares might be enough to hide message. This gives you $n!$ different ways to reconstruct the message. So in this case you may not need random dummies at all.

Comment: @DilipSarwate What is your idea about "GuuT Boy" answer (in the comment)? It seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @mikeazo I know that you know SSS related work very well (as well as the other areas). Can you please tell me how two secrets in SSS can be multiplied non-interactively?

Comment: @user153465 you mean so that you end up with shares of the product of the two secrets?

Comment: @mikeazo Yes, that's right

Comment: @user153465 simply multiplying the shares with the same index would give you a sharing of the product. There are 2 problems with this, however. 1) The threshold has doubled. So if you were doing $t=n/2$ out of $n$ secret sharing, you would now need all $n$ shares to reconstruct. 2) The coefficients of the polynomial that results in the sharing of the product are not independent. The only way we know around this is to use interaction.

Comment: @GuutBoy I think the Shares are not necessarily "indistinguishable" from the random  elements (as the coefficients of the random polynomial are the same for all the shares).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let us first consider the problem without involving Shamir secret-sharing
at all.  Suppose that $n = 140$ and that the secret $\sigma$ is a 140-byte Twitter message. The space is thus restricted considerably, from all possible $256$ byte values to the printable
characters permitted to be used in Twitter messages, and the distribution in this restricted space might also be nonuniform because of etaion shrdlu. The secret sharing
is trivial: each of the $140$ shareholders gets one byte, and the secret
is recovered only when all $140$ shares are assembled in the correct
order.

An adversary is given a large number composite number $N$ of bytes 
(arranged into a matrix if the OP so desires, though I am not sure why
this imposes some structure on the data) including
the $140$ shares and the other $N-140$
entries filled in "at random". Can the
adversary recover the secret with large enough probability to be
a significant concern?  Well, the answer might depend on the
assumptions. If the $N-140$ "other" bytes are "filled in at random"
from the space of all $256$ bytes, then the adversary can simply
discard all bytes that are not part of the Twitter character set.
This reduces the workspace from $N$ bytes to
approximately $p(N-n) + n$ bytes where $p$ is the ratio of the size
of the Twitter character set 
(80? 96?) to $256$. It might also be possible to make some educated
guesses and apply the known distribution of the message set to discount excessive numbers of letters x or q or z etc or punctuation marks, etc.  So, with no secret sharing, the extraneous bytes that
the adversary is handed should be chosen not at at random, but
roughly with the probabilities with which they occur in Twitter
messages.

Many of these concerns go away when Shamir secret sharing is used.
Now, the shares are of the same length as the secret, but
share $\sigma_i$ is the *value* of the polynomial
$$S(x) = \sigma + a_1 x + a_2x^2 + \cdots + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}$$
(where the $a_i$ are *randomly chosen* nonzero entries) at some
nonzero element $\alpha_i$ in the field.  Even if $\sigma$ is restricted,
these random polynomial coefficients ensure that the shares
$$S(\alpha_1), ~S(\alpha_2),~ S(\alpha_3),~ \ldots,~ S(\alpha_n)$$
essentially look like random choices. In fact, some of them might
even equal $0$.  Thus, if we fill the $N-n$ other entries with *other*
random choices (allowing $0$ as a choice too), the $N$ possible
shares handed to the adversary will conceal the true shares very well.
I don't have a formal proof for this, but I doubt that any statistical
test can distinguish the actual shares from the fakes with even a
minuscule chance of success.  Of course, one must ensure that $N$
is much larger than $n$ so that there are enough . I venture to suggest that $N = O(n^2)$ will be found to be more than adequate, and 
perhaps even something like
$10n$ might work well enough.

Comment: There is one problem here: the shares in Shamir secret sharing  may not be uniformly random elements of the field. Thus, the adversary may distinguish them from dummy values. As I could not find any paper stating the shares are random elements of the field, also the shares are related to each other as the random coefficients remain the same for the shares.

Comment: Well, but you could simply sample the dummy values from the same distribution. E.g., if we continue the Twitter + Shamir case you could simply produce shares for dummy Twitter messages. In general, you should be able to generate the same distribution by sharing messages that follow the same distribution as your real message. The only issue is that you end up with enormous storage requirements...

Comment: Even without Shamir secret sharing, permute the characters of Twitter messages "Attack at dawn" "Attack at noon" "Retreat at noon" etc and hand them over to the adversary.

Comment: Just for your information: http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-31540-4_12#page-1

Comment: In a paper client hides all $x_i$ values and gives only $f(x_i)$ values to a malicious server. The paper I cited shows that that scheme is insecure and can be attacked. However, I do not know whether the attack can be applied to the scheme I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @mephisto In terms of storage requirement, 10-20 times in not a big deal and in general it's $O(n)$ where $n$ is number of shares. The $\textbf{security}$ matters a lot to me.

Comment: You have to be aware that you do not get perfect secrecy anymore when using this scheme but only computational security. Now you can increase security increasing the number of dummies. However, in the end you will probably not be more secure than using for example AES... in both cases the attacker just has to guess the key for a permutation.

Comment: @mephisto The computational security would suffice, but I'm still not convinced if we can get computational security using the above scheme!

Comment: @user153465 Could you please move your discussions to _chat?_  As the original writer of the answer, I get pinged every time one of you writes a response, and I have no interest in the issue that you are arguing about.

Comment: @mephisto Could you please move your discussions to chat? As the original writer of the answer, I get pinged every time one of you writes a response, and I have no interest in the issue that you are arguing about.